# Set data to input depending radcombobox value inside radgrid telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, telerik-grid, telerik-ajax

I created a radgrid witch editmode = "bath".

Inside this grid I've declared a radcombobox using GridtTemplateColumn, I want to set value to a radtextbox depending of selected value of the combo (it is inside the grid too).

I couldn´t find how to do this, I was traying to do it on "SelectedIndexChanged" event of the combo but I could not find the row index.

[Visual Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG2px.png)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The SelectedIndexChanged is a server event. Subscribe to the OnClientSelectedIndexChanged event of the RadComboBox instead.

You can access the current row as follows:

```
                function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, args) {
                        var currentRow = $(sender.get_element()).parents("tr.rgRow,tr.rgAltRow")[0];
                       // Find the textbox and set its text value
            }
```